# Create new instance of a certain type dynamically

Tags: c#, types, casting

I have this parent class "Component", and some classes inherited from it "Component1", "Component2".. etc

I have a list `List<Component> Components` and I need to create new instances of some classes that are inherited from it and add them to the list `Components`

The way I am doing it now is something like

```
private void AddComponent(string componentType)
{
    if (componentType == "component1")
    {
        Components.Add(new component1());
    }
    if (componentType == "component2")
    {
        Components.Add(new component2());
    }
    // and so on
}
```

As my code gets larger, I need to add more components. So I wonder if there is a better way to go about things.

I looked around and found this way which didn't work for me:

```
    var newComponent = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(componentType));
    newComponent = Convert.ChangeType(newComponent, Type.GetType(componentType));

    Components.Add(newComponent);
```

it says: `cannot convert from 'object' to Component`

EDIT: Solved, I forgot to do casting.

Comment: Activator.CreateInstance returns object. Components.Add() accepts a Component. You'll need to cast at some point. eg. Components.Add((Component)newComponent);

Comment: @moreON Silly me I guess. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If the derived classes have empty constructors and you're okay using the component type directly instead of passing a string representation, you could do something like this:

```
private void AddComponent<T>() where T : Component, new()
{
  Components.Add(new T());
}

/* ... */

AddComponent<Component1>();
AddComponent<Component2>();
```

This assumes `Component` is the base class from which all other components derive.

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to do this:

```
var newComponent = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(componentType));
Components.Add((Component)newComponent);
```

`Activator.CreateInstance` will simply create the object - there is no need to convert it to anything else. Just a simple cast will let you add it to your list.